# Draw Border around ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I go about drawing a border with a specified width and color around a listbox?
Can this be done without overriding the OnPaint method?

Comment: that's what the OnPaint event is for.....

Comment: Overriding it and drawing it works, however, I cannot see the listbox items anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Neutone's suggestion, here is a handy function to add and remove a `Panel`-based border around any control, even if it is nested..

Simply pass in the `Color` and size you want, and if you want a `BorderStyle`. To remove it again pass in `Color.Transparent`!

```
void setBorder(Control ctl, Color col, int width, BorderStyle style)
{
    if (col == Color.Transparent)
    {
        Panel pan = ctl.Parent as Panel;
        if (pan == null) { throw new Exception("control not in border panel!");}
        ctl.Location = new Point(pan.Left + width, pan.Top + width);
        ctl.Parent = pan.Parent;
        pan.Dispose();

    }
    else
    {
        Panel pan = new Panel();
        pan.BorderStyle = style; 
        pan.Size = new Size(ctl.Width + width * 2, ctl.Height + width * 2);
        pan.Location = new Point(ctl.Left - width, ctl.Top - width);
        pan.BackColor = col;
        pan.Parent = ctl.Parent;
        ctl.Parent = pan;
        ctl.Location = new Point(width, width);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want this to work right with < 3 pixel borders you have to set the parent control borderstyle to none. Othewise, youll only get your border on the top and left.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a list box within a panel and have the panel serve as a border. The panel backcolor can be used to create a colored border. This doesn't require much code. Having a colored border around a form component can be an effective way of conveying status.

Comment: In fact you can write a `SetBorder(Control ctl, Color color)` function, which creates, sizes and places the `Panel` on the fly and put the `ListBox` into it in just a few lines of code.. pass null or Color.Transparent for the Color to revert the action..

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the ListBox control is that it does not raise the OnPaint method so you can not use it to draw a border around the control.

There are two methods to paint a custom border around the ListBox:

1. Use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)` in the constructor, then you can use the OnPaint method to draw the border.
2. Override [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=netframework-4.8) method that handles operating system messages identified in the Message structure.

I used the last method to paint a custom border around the control, this will eliminate the need to use a Panel to provide a custom border for the ListBox.

```
public partial class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public MyListBox()
    {

        // SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(m);
        var switchExpr = m.Msg;
        switch (switchExpr)
        {
            case 0xF:
                {
                    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics;
                    g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.Default;
                    int borderWidth = 4;
                    Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
                    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, borderWidth) { Alignment = Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Center })
                    {
                        g.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
                    }

                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 6 years later, you've come to my resue ;)