# How to Change black border color of flat listbox in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

I want to customize the border color of listbox (with borderstyle as fixedsingle)  in .net, Is it possible to change that ?

Please help.

Comment: you want this?http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_bordercolor

Comment: IT researcher is referring to winforms :) 'fixedsingle'

Comment: The BorderColor property seems only to be available for WebControls in C#. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901007/draw-border-around-listbox

Comment: Check `ListBox.BorderColor` Property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.bordercolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The color used for the border in winforms is part of the theme chosen by the user and is not meant to be controlled by the app.  You could host it on a panel but that is a fairly expensive way to go. @RahulHendawe that is from `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

Comment: @Plutonix i agree with you its expensive way to go, but it will achieve what   
IT researcher is after, if its only being used once...whats the harm.

Comment: Another duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901007/draw-border-around-listbox. The solution proposed there is the same ugly hack that David came up with, albeit with a slightly more elegant implementation that does little to minimize the hackishness. Plutonix's comment that the border is part of the theme chosen by the user and should not be overridden by the app bears emphasizing. Any time you find yourself working really hard to do something in UI programming, you are probably working against the system and shouldn't be doing it that way.

Comment: @CodyGray totally agree with you, the below is indeed is a hack, but gets the results IT researcher was looking for, either way you look at it you will have to do some sort of hack to achieve the result be that owner drawn controls, dynamically adding the controls like in the post you have outlined above, or some other sort of hack not already outline, the below is just one way to do it :)

Comment: I have added a new answer that you can use to draw a border around the ListBox without the need to use Panel control https://stackoverflow.com/a/60640672/5514131

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done on the ListBox control in winforms, but you could add the ListBox on top of a panel and have the back color of the panel mimic the look.

[image]

Its not an ideal way to do what you want, but it will achieve what you are after.

Comment: It's really not a very nice solutation, yet it works. You could create a new user control where you do exactly this.

Comment: This is really the definition of "ugly hack." It's a hack, and it's ugly on two different levels. First, the hack itself is ugly. Second, the result is ugly because the border is not even all the way around. I'm not really sure why you would create *two* controls when you only need one. If it is really so important that you have a border, you can owner-draw the ListBox and create your own border.